# No module named profile

Tags: python

when i tried to search bookdetails from library of congress using python with the help of z3950 module, I got following error

```
from PyZ3950 import zoom

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyZ3950/zoom.py", line 72, in <module>
    from PyZ3950 import z3950
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyZ3950/z3950.py", line 72, in <module>
    from PyZ3950 import asn1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyZ3950/asn1.py", line 2009, in <module>
    import profile
ImportError: No module named profile
```

please help me for a solution

Comment: That's odd; it's [a standard module](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://www.kindle-maps.com/blog/profiling-python-in-ubuntu.html) suggests that it is not part of the default install of Python on Ubuntu 11.04. It says:

> You will need to [enable the multiverse repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab) first.
>
> The solution is to install the `python-profiler` package, i.e. do this command:
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude install python-profiler
> ```
>
> Then you can use python profile as normal.